# Get Response Header/Body

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, http-headers

I'm developing a firefox addon and I'm listening to http responses like this:

```
var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(httpObserver, "http-on-examine-response", false);
```

Which calls my httpObserver object that looks like this:

```
var httpObserver =
{
 observe : function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) 
 {  
            aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
            httpstatus = aSubject.responseStatus;
            if(httpstatus == 200 && aSubject.contentType.toString().indexOf("text/") != -1)
            {
                alert("URL: " + aSubject.name + "\r\nStatus: " + httpstatus + "\r\nContentType: " + aSubject.contentType); //Works great
                alert("Body: " + aSubject.responseText); //Is undefined, why?
            }
            else if(httpstatus == 404 && aSubject.contentType.toString().indexOf("text/html") != -1)
                alert("Page not found!\r\nURL: " + aSubject.name + "\r\nContentType: " + aSubject.contentType);
 }
};
```

I've got the following problem(s):

I'd like to get the **whole** body and header from the response but I don't know how.
I once read that it could be a problem that the server is not in the same domain, but how does the firefox handles it then?

I already did a lot of research but I didn't find anything usefull, maybe I missed something..

Btw.: I've got access to the request object as well if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use [`nsITraceableChannel` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/NsITraceableChannel) for that, it is implemented by all HTTP requests. This allows you to replace the channel listener by one of your own, so you can read out the data in `onDataAvailable` call before passing it on to the original listener. There is some example code doing just that here: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/